# Convert Queryable Byte to Byte[]

Tags: c#, linq

This is my Linq Code to Grab the Byte ARRAY value of the First id = 1. Id is a Distinct value so there won't be any duplicates. The linq query, does exactly what it's suppose to do. Grabs the value of the table and puts it in a queryable. I'm wondering how do I just get the value OR convert it to the "Byte array" format I want it to be in.

```
ctx.Files.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => x.FileName)
```

Comment: If you want the single result, call `.FirstOrDefault()` after the `Select(...)` and I am guessing that you do not get a byte array but a string array.

Comment: @Silvermind, if there's, at most, one and only one record with the same Id, `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` are the correct operators to use.

Comment: @PauloMorgado No, If you are searching for a record which has a unique constraint, you should use `FirstOrDefault()`. If you have for example a huge collection, `FirstOrDefault()` will stop at the first hit, while `SingleOrDefault()` keeps running to find a duplicate, which for large collection can be a huge performance cost and since it is a unique value, it is overkill. When there is no constraint on being unique and you're absolutely depending on a single result and you are not sure, because someone might have screwed up; use `SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: No @Silvermind. They are semantically different. If only one exists, you should use `Single` (or `SingleOrDefault`). If more than one exists, then something went wrong and you can't trust the data. `First` (or `FirstOrDefault`) mean "give me the first one - I don't care which one it is". If you get to the place where you parked your car to get your car you want `Single`. you don't even want `SngleOrDefault` because it would mean you would be just fine if your car had been stolen. You also don't want `First` because you might get some car that was dropped on top of yours.

Comment: @PauloMorgado No, Please read my comment again, because I am saying: Single vs First equals Should vs Irrelevant and not Should vs Don't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query returns a string, you can read the file like this:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(    
    ctx.Files.Where(x => x.Id == 1).Select(x => x.FileName).Single()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `.ToArray()` at the result of the linq-statement